# mysql partitioning error A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

Tags: mysql, laravel, partitioning

On MySQL 8 I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `float_values` (
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `attribute_id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `value` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` date NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `float_values`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `float_values_created_at_unique` (`created_at`);

ALTER TABLE `float_values`
  MODIFY `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

with this schema:

```
Schema::create('float_values', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('attribute_id');
            $table->float('value');

            $table->date('created_at');
            $table->date('updated_at');
        });
```

after table created I did this for partitioning on created_at column:

```
ALTER TABLE float_values 
PARTITION BY HASH( YEAR(created_at) )
PARTITIONS 4
```

but I get this error:

> Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Unrecognized alter operation. (near "" at position 0) SQL query:
>
> ALTER TABLE float_values PARTITION BY HASH( YEAR(created_at) )
> PARTITIONS 4
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1503 - A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

I know that the question is duplicate but answers didn't help me!

the error says that we have to announce created_at as primary but we cant have two primary keys I changed created_at to unique but the problem still exists

Comment: To quote the man, "Don't bother using hash."

Answer (score 7):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html says:

> All columns used in the partitioning expression for a partitioned table must be part of every unique key that the table may have.
>
> In other words, every unique key on the table must use every column in the table's partitioning expression. This also includes the table's primary key, since it is by definition a unique key.

This is a blocker for many people who want to use table partitioning in MySQL. You can't always partition by the column you want to partition by, because it's either not in a unique key, or there is some other unique (or primary) key in the table.

Remember: the partitioning expression must be part of **EVERY** unique key of the table.

Even if you were to make `created_at` a unique key, there is still the fact that the primary key of this table is on the `id` column.

There is no way to use partitioning on a MySQL table if you have both a PRIMARY KEY and a UNIQUE KEY, and these two keys have no column in common.

Comment: Thank you Bill, I just didn't know how to add a primary key with two columns and I fount that finally I just had to create the table and then add those primary keys together I now just don't know is it OK to have id and a date field as primary key together or not!

Comment: It means `id` is no longer assured to be unique on its own. You can have many rows with the same `id` value as long as they have different timestamps. This solves the partitioning problem you had, but it means your table constraint is pretty useless as a primary key.

Comment: In this example I don't use id and it's not a concern because it's a table for historical data charts and some like this, queries conditions are just on created_at field. Thank you very much Bill

Comment: @HassanShojaei - If you don't need `id`, get rid of it.  Clutter costs.

Comment: @RickJames I don't know yet it will be used of not so I will keep it but I will hold that in mind, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.

when I was migrating the table it created a primary increment column on id so when I was doing the alter partition query it was telling me that partitioning column have to be a primary key!
What I shall be doing was that create a table without primary keys and increments column in my schema and then after a simple table without any primary keys created I did create a primary key contains **id, created_at** columns like this:

First this:

```
CREATE TABLE `float_values` (
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `attribute_id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `value` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` date NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

With this schema:

```
Schema::create('float_values', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('attribute_id');
            $table->float('value');

            $table->date('created_at');
            $table->primary(['id', 'created_at']);
            $table->date('updated_at');
        });
```

and then this query:

```
alter TABLE float_values add primary key (`id`, `created_at`)
```

Answer (score 0):

`PARTITION BY HASH` is useless; don't bother figuring out how to make it work.

Furthermore, as a general rule, Partitioning is not useful unless you have at least a million rows.  Since you are asking for a `DATE` to be `UNIQUE`, I suspect you will have not more than a few thousand rows.

If you would like to explain the purpose of the table, its eventual size, the goal for using Hash, and some `SELECTs` that you will use, I can probably explain how to achieve your goals without partitioning.

**Scenarios:**

For these queries:

```
... WHERE id = 111 AND created_at BETWEEN ... AND ... -- case 1
... WHERE attribute_id = 222                             -- case 2
... WHERE attribute_id = 333 AND created_at BETWEEN ... AND ... -- case 3
```

Then your table might be non-partitioned:

```
CREATE TABLE `float_values` (
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,  -- debatable
  `attribute_id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `value` double(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` date NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` date NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY(id),                   -- for case 1
  INDEX(attribute_id, created_at)    -- for cases 2, 3
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Thank you Rick. I am dealing with an EAV schema, rows number is about 50 million, I separated data to 3 table each have about 15 million, only select I will use is historical selects like: select .... where created_at between 'date1' and 'date2'

Comment: @HassanShojaei - Do `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT ...` -- You will find that that query _always_ accesses _all_ partitions when using `PARTITION BY HASH(created_at)`  In other words, it will be _slower_ than if the table were not partitioned.  Aren't you also testing on `id` or `attribute_id`?

Comment: So what is the better idea to do this?

Comment: @HassanShojaei - See my addition.  If you have other queries, show me.  I will see if other indexes are needed.  Another potential issue:  WIll you be deleting "old" data"?

Comment: no other queries and maybe in future I will delete old data or archive them but not now.